# C# HttpListener Partial Content

Tags: c#, http, tcplistener, httplistener

I'm writing an application similar to `HFS` which is a `HTTP File Server` with customization themes in `HTML/CSS/JS` and i would like to be able to serve my files in multiple parts, because most of download managers connect to the server through multiple connections and download the file as `8` pieces, and that feature ultimately boosts the download speed, and it makes the download to have the capability to resumed and paused.

As far as i know the `HTTP's Partial Content` makes this possible, i've looked around the web but couldn't find any good example of how to implement it in my code where i use `HttpListener` to serve webpages and files.

I've seen somewhere that someone suggested to use `TcpListener` instead but as my whole app works on `HttpListener` and haven't really find any good examples of Serving Partial Content with `TcpListener` to switch.

The webserver is multi-threaded and doesn't have any problem handling many requests through different connection simultaneously.
But whenever i download a huge file with `IDM` it just serves the content though a single connection and IDM shows that the server isn't capable of serving `"206"` (`HTTP Partial Content`)

Here's the code that i'm currently using to serve files:

```
context.Response.ContentType = GetMeme(filename);

Stream input = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
context.Response.ContentLength64 = input.Length;

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 16];
int nbytes;
while ((nbytes = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, nbytes);
input.Close();

context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

I tried to get the buffer offset from the HTTP heads but it fails to close the stream due to the offset and says `Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.`

Is there any better alternative?
Can even HttpListener handle HTTP: 206 correctly?
How would partial content work on TcpListener?

Any useful links and information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this answer is not pretending to be complete, it's just so many things to talk about in this context. But as a beginning...

The listener you use has no relation to it. Your code should be aware of `RANGE` HTTP header. When `RANGE` is supplied, read and serve the file as specified in this header + send 206. Otherwise, serve the entire file and send 200.

It's not the buffer offset you get, but the file offset.

First set response code and other metadata (headers), and write to the stream as the last step.

And you'll probably have to completely change the way you actually serve files. For instance, call CopyToAsync() on FileStream you have.

And it's not `Meme`, it's `MIME`.

Comment: Thank you for the info i'll try them as post the complete feedback asap, and yeah i know it's MIME, sometimes i use funny names for methods and vars :))